# Using Macbook Pro 5,1 Running Ubuntu to Create a Bootable Lion USB Installer (?)

Tags: linux, macbook, osx-lion, installer

I'm having a nightmare of a time attempting to create a working Bootable USB of OSX Lion from a Macbook Pro running Ubuntu.

I have followed just about all the best guides online to format and image the USB to no avail or success.

I've had to image the Macbook with Ubuntu Lucid after the DVD drive broke and hte Recovery partition was found to be empty.  All efforts to install Ubuntu from USB failed and I was forced to use a Live CD install from external superdrive.

Now that I've got a working OS, Ubuntu, I want to create a bootable Lion Install to reimage the macbook with OSX Lion.

I've followed many a guide online, but all are pointing to use an existing Mac OSX to prepare the USB media.

at the moment I am trying out a fix using 3 partitions, first fat16 with syslinux, last with Refit, which was written from *.cdr format to the partition using unetbootin, the middle partition was left untouched and now I am using dd if= of =/dev/ to write the InstallESD.dmg image.

I am hoping someone has faced such an issue or has some pointers.

I have used up my bank of booleen searches in google and followed all the guides I could find which were semi applicable.. none successfull, all theoretical however :)